# Update GitLab repo from a Github repo

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm having trouble updating a GitLab repo from a Github repo. An update was released for the Github repo that I've forked, and I would like to incorporate that update into my fork. Does anyone have any way to do this other than replacing the project files manually?

Comment: `git remote add other-github GITHUB_URL; git pull other-github master` ?

Comment: @JavaNut13 Will this work for git repositories other than Github? Or does it not matter? For example: `git remote add http://git.site.org/mathewwe/ftc_app.git; git pull https://github.com/ftctechnh/ftc_app.git beta`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: It will work with any git repo. You do need to give a name to the remote that you're adding (in my example it is `other-github`) which identifies the repo and URL to pull from.

Comment: If you need your GitLab repo to be updated whenever there's a change in GitHub, perhaps the best way to do that is using GitLab import and set it up to mirror the GH repo. But I'm not sure it's what you need here. You could also use `git fetch` if can't import for some reason.

Answer (score 8):

Gitlab allows [automatic mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html) but it appears to be a [paid](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/) feature.

Navigate to your project’s **Settings > Repository** and expand the
    **Mirroring repositories** section (only seen if you have a paid for version).

- Enter a repository URL.
- Select Pull from the Mirror direction dropdown.
- Select an authentication method from the Authentication method dropdown, if necessary.
- If necessary,
  check the following boxes:

  - Overwrite diverged branches.
  - Trigger pipelines for mirror updates.
  - Only mirror protected branches.
- Click the Mirror repository button to save the configuration.

Comment: oooh wow, one missing tiny operation to try to force the user into using their repo or paying... pathetic but at least I find out early not to use them.